# Packaging app for platform win32 x64 taking too long using electron v5.0.6

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I developped a web app with angular i need to package my web app using electron , it all seems fine until i run electron-packager , it takes forever , i dont know if it is supposed to be this slow or is there something wrong ?
ps : im on windows 7

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "recherche-final",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build  && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-packager."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "electron": "^5.0.6",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.1",
    "electron-winstaller": "^3.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

i expect my app.exe

Comment: How long is "forever"? I'd expect e.g. 2-5 minutes for a simple app being built on a fast computer. Keep an eye on the task manager to see if CPU or memory use is very high.

Comment: it keeps on running for hours with no result

Comment: is there any output at all?

Comment: no output at all

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer but just in case it helps anybody else- Have you checked how you have packaged your app? Make sure that your package.json files for angular and Electron are different. You are probably packing all the angular node modules as well into the electron application which is not necessary.

https://medium.com/@hellobharadwaj/electron-plus-angular-react-why-use-2-different-package-json-files-361ae47d07f3

Comment: Very useful tip, thanks! :)